# Removing Brackets and the content

Tags: mysql

I have a column in my database called Horse_Name. This currently includes the country if outside of UK in brackets (ire),(fra) ect.

Is it possible to run a query to remove the brackets and the content very much like in excel whereby you can replace all (*) within the given column?

An example would be as follows

```
Current            Outcome
----------------+--------------    
Horse_Name      |  Horse_Name
----------------+--------------    
Rocket(FRA)     |   Rocket   
Apple Jade(IRE) |   Apple Jade
Zac             |   Zac
```

I would like to go through the whole column named Horse_Name to remove the brackets and data.

I have tried the following code but it only finds the values and does not replace them

```
SELECT REPLACE(Horse_Name, 
               SUBSTRING(Horse_Name, LOCATE('(', Horse_Name), LENGTH(Horse_Name) - LOCATE(')', 
               REVERSE(Horse_Name)) - LOCATE('(', Horse_Name) + 2), '') AS Horse_Name
FROM  TFResults;
```

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've set up this example:

```
create table tbl (horse_name varchar(100));
insert into tbl values ('Rocket(FRA)'),('Apple Jade(IRE) 2'),('Zac');
```

If last parenthese is located always at end of the string you could use next syntax:

```
select case when locate('(', horse_name) = 0 
            then horse_name
            else left(horse_name, locate('(', horse_name) - 1)
       end as horse_name            
from   tbl;
```

But if there are additional characters after the last parenthese you could CONCAT left and right substrings in this way:

```
select case when locate('(', horse_name) = 0 
            then horse_name
            else concat(left(horse_name, locate('(', horse_name) - 1),
                        right(horse_name, length(horse_name) - locate(')', horse_name)))
       end as horse_name            
from   tbl;
```

This is the final result (note I've added a `2` after `(IRE)`:

> ```
> | horse_name   |
> | :----------- |
> | Rocket       |
> | Apple Jade 2 |
> | Zac          |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c9491ae95dc96073aa365c8144c7c937)*

Comment: I'm glad to help.